# My dropdown list in a bootstrap navbar does not work propretly in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, navbar

I am trying to implement a boostrap navbar with a drop down list in asp.net . Everything seems to work, it looks nice but the problem with dropdown list, instead of going down, how it does normaly, my list goes to the right on button press.
As shown in the image [Connect text should drop down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIYfh.png)

Here is my code sample

```
     <head runat="server">
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->

<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="Styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<title>Dokumentløsning</title>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />


<environment names="Development">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
</environment>
<environment names="Staging,Production">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          asp-fallback-href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          asp-fallback-test-class="sr-only" asp-fallback-test-property="position" asp-fallback-test-value="absolute" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.min.css" asp-append-version="true" />
</environment>
```

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <h1 runat="server"></h1>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">

<!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
<div class="navbar-header">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand
     </a>
</div>

<!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-center">
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Tools <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Connect via mail</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Scan a file</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>   
  </ul>

 <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
     <li><a href="#">Setup</a></li>
     <li><a href="#" >Log out</a></li>
      </ul>

</div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
```

I got all the bootstrap links in my project and still did not make it work

May the problem be because of the gridview table right under the navbar or it is because I messed up something with scripts

Thank you indeed!

Comment: Check the order of JQuery and Bootstrap Js scripts. `JQuery should be always on top of Bootstrap script.`

Comment: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
this is the order of my scripts

Comment: Don't include multiple Jquery script, try with removing any one.

Comment: Still did not do the job, I am wondering if I downloaded the right bootstrap packages and added them to the right place in project and if the link to them is correct, intructions seems to be right because the design work, but the funcionality does not

Comment: Debug in browser and check that all resources are loading in DOM or not